# Jekyll Site Not Showing CSS on Custom Domains

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages, blogs, custom-domain

I have created a blog using jekyll that is hosted via github pages. When I view the site locally using `jekyll serve` it loads correctly with all the css & assets showing up. However, when I view the same site on a custom domain ([www.switcorn.com](http://www.switcorn.com)) the css and assets are not showing up properly everywhere except the home page.

The source code is found here: https://github.com/ishu3101/blog/tree/v1

Comment: The link does not work. I can't find the problem in the code (stylesheets references seem alright). Try to load the site and view the console of your browser (F12 and reload the page). Maybe it can tell you if there's any problem loading the assets.

Comment: Can you try again. it is working for me but the style sheets isnt working for the tags page.

Comment: I get an "unauthorized" error